# Knockout.js Observable Not Getting Set

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this code that is not doing what it suppose to do. It is a knockout.js project and this object;

```
self.eventItem = ko.observable({
  recordId: ko.observable(0),
  selectedEventType: ko.observable()
}
```

This object is initialized in this function. There is a lot of code in here but debugging this for a while shows that "self.originalEventItem().EventTypeId" return a value of "6" and it is a number. That value is set to selectedEventType;

```
self.loadInitialData = function () {

        self.pageLoaded(false);

        var step1 = common.getEventDetailsForEdit(self.eventItem().recordId()); //step1

        var step2 = step1.then(
            function (data) {
                if (data.IsError) {
                    toastr.error(data.ErrorMessage, "Error");
                    return new $.Deferred().reject();
                } else {
                    self.originalEventItem(data.Data);
                    return common.getEventTypes();
                }
            }); //step2

        var step3 = step2.then(
            function (data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        self.eventTypes.push(new APOLLO.DropDownType(item.RecordId, item.Name));
                        self.originalEventTypes.push(item);
                    });
                    self.eventItem().selectedEventType(self.originalEventItem().EventTypeId);
                    self.eventTypeChanged();

                }
            }
        );//step3

    };//loadInitialData
```

Now when we enter the "self.eventTypeChanged()" function and call the "self.eventItem().selectedEventType()" it will return undefined? Here is the function for the "eventTypeChanged()";

```
self.eventTypeChanged = function () {
        if (self.originalEventTypes) {
            var newValue = self.eventItem().selectedEventType();
            for (var i = 0; i < self.originalEventTypes.length; i++) {
                if (self.originalEventTypes[i].RecordId === newValue) {
                    self.eventItem().selectedFullEventType(self.originalEventTypes[i]);
                }
            }

            self.resetLists();
            self.populateChildLists();
        }
    };
```

The variable "newValue" is undefined. I debugged all the way through knockout.js and it looks like it is being set but for some reason it is not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you've defined your eventItem to have observable properties, but throughout the code, you use a mix of knockout and javascript assignment. watch the parens

Comment: In the else statement, what does data.Data equal?

Comment: data.Data returns JSON object and populates the originalEventItem. All values on the originalEventItem are correct. Just when selectedEventType is set to a value it stays undefined.

Comment: Is it making it past `if (data.length > 0)` in step3?

Comment: Something out of left field but it's bitten me in the past.  Is anything bound via an options binding ?  It has a tendency to reset the value target observable back to undefined if it's not in the option list.  1. You set observable bound via the value binding.  2. The options binding cross checks the value against the options array.  3. If no match resets value observable to undefined

Comment: I tried passing the value to the eventTypeChanged function and when I set the self.eventItem().selectedEventType(eventTypeId); I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" the value of eventTypeId is 6